# How to call a method using intent

Tags: android

Is there any possible way to call a method at the time when call the intent activity. I want to display only particular method when i switch over from one activity to another using intent call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `extras` bundle in the `Intent`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtra("your_condition", int_condition);
```

Then on onCreate of the `Intent`

```
int_condition=getIntent.getIntExtra("your_condition");
```

Now you can use this

```
if(int_condition==0)
{
//Call the method
}
else
{
//method you want
}
```

Again there is another option for you as you can pass the method name  as a parameter in your `Intent`, assumes that you are sending `mathod_name` as an `extra` to the `Bundle`

```
String method_name=getIntent.getIntExtra("method_name");
Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod (method_name, parameterTypes)
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```

Answer (score -8):

Not exactly sure what your asking ... but this intent will call someone

For example

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", 
ContentURI.create("tel:" + phone)); 
startActivity(i);
```

You have to have the

```
<uses-permission id="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Otherwise send your probelm clearly. i am not able to inderstand

Comment: I think he wants to call a specific method from the intent, most likely another app's method. That's why I say depending on the calling intent another logic should be taken in the app flow. It's a design issue only.