# How to call a method unless it was opened as an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to trigger a method when an Activity is opened by an intent.
I found `onNewIntent()` on articles but I have no idea how that works.

For example if I had the method `loadData()`. In the `loadData` method I will receive an Intent and get an array extra.

```
public void loadData(){
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
contactsList = (ArrayList<Contact>)bundle.getSerializable("array");
}
```

But i only want loadData() to be called unless it is opened by an intent or it will throw a bug.

This article [How to call a method using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946171/how-to-call-a-method-using-intent) was similar to what I wanted because it seems like the `getIntent` is called in the `oncreate`. I don't know if that will work or not.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check intent have values or null .if its have the value call your method

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
loadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a parameter to the Activity and check if that parameter exists to trigger the method. Does this fit what you want?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("loadData", true);
```

In the new activity, check that value:

```
Boolean loadData = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("loadData");
if(loadData) {...}
```